# How to add a button with click event on UITableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In my main page, I created a xib file for UITableViewCell. I'm loading the cell from that xib file and its working fine.

Inside of the cell I have some labels and buttons. I'm aiming to change the label by clicking to the button on the cell.

My Code likes below

```
import UIKit


class SepetCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet var barcode: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var fav: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var strep: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var times: UILabel!



    @IBAction func favoriteClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        println(sender.tag)
        println(times.text)

        SepetViewController().favorite(sender.tag)



    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

This is my xib files behind codes as .swift.

The codes in the main page likes below:

```
  import UIKit
import CoreData

class SepetViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @
  IBOutlet
  var sepetTable: UITableView!
    var barcodes: [CART] = []

  let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {


      var nib = UINib(nibName: "SepetTableCell", bundle: nil)
      self.sepetTable.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "productCell")
    }
    fetchLog()
    sepetTable.reloadData()
  }

  func fetchLog() {

    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
      barcodes = CART.getElements(moc);
    }
  }



  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
    return self.barcodes.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productCell") as ? SepetCell


    if cell == nil {
      println("cell nil")

    }



    let product: CART
    product = barcodes[indexPath.row]



    cell!.barcode ? .text = product.barcode
    cell!.name ? .text = product.name
    cell!.fav.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell!
  }

  func favorite(tag: Int) {



  }
}
```

When i clicked fav button inside of the Cell. I wanted to change times label text to anything for example.

When I clicked to the fav button, the event will gone to the SepetCell.swift favoriteClicked(sender: UIButton) function.

So if i try to call:
SepetViewController().favorite(sender.tag)

It will go inside of the

```
func favorite(tag: Int) {

      sepetTable.reloadData()

    }
```

but sepetTable is nil when it is gone there. I think it is because of when I call this SepetViewController().favorite(sender.tag) function. It firstly creates SepetViewController class. So because of object is not setted it is getting null.

How can I reach that sepetTable or what is the best way to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Popular patterns for solving this problem are closures and delegates.
If you want to use closures, you would do something like this:

```
final class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    var actionBlock: (() -> Void)? = nil
```

then

```
    @IBAction func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
        actionBlock?()
    }
```

then in your tableview delegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier") as? MyCell
    cell?.actionBlock = {
       //Do whatever you want to do when the button is tapped here
    }
```

---

A popular alternative is to use the delegate pattern:

```
    protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
        func didTapButtonInCell(_ cell: MyCell)
    }

    final class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
        weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?
```

then

```
    @IBAction func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didTapButtonInCell(self)
    }
```

..
Now in your view controller:

then in your tableview delegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier") as? MyCell
    cell?.delegate = self
```

And add conformance to the protocol like this:

```
extension MyViewController: MyCellDelegate {
    didTapButtonInCell(_ cell: MyCell) {
       //Do whatever you want to do when the button is tapped here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot. its worked for me. If I want to send someting from SepetCell to tableView what should I do? For example, I have a strepper and when I click on it I want to change the label's value

Comment: ok I found it by some try:)
I made some changes on the code like:

 var onFavButtonTapped : ((Int) -> Void)? = nil ****
        if let onButtonTapped = self.onButtonTapped {
           onButtonTapped(3)
        }
****  cell!.onButtonTapped = {(x: Int) in
            println(x)
            
        }

Comment: great to hear!. BTW, if you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting :)

Comment: yeah i already tried to do it but because of I'm new user, system is not allowing me to do it. It wants at least 15 reputation. Sorry :) When I have 15 rep I will do it :)

Comment: this is probably one of the most beautiful solutions i've seen since i've started writing in swift. thank you for writing it!

Answer (score 1):

All patterns above are **fine**.
my two cents, in case You add **by code** (for example multiple different cells and so on..)
there is a FAR simple solution.

As buttons allow to specify a "target" You can pass directly the controller AND action to cell/button when setting it.

In controller:

```
let selector = #selector(self.myBtnAction)
setupCellWith(target: self, selector: selector)
```

...

in custom cell with button:

```
final func setupCellWith(target: Any? selector: Selector){
       btn.addTarget(target, 
        action: selector,
       for: .touchUpInside)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    
    //cell.buttonPressed add in Your tableViewCell file
    
    cell.buttonPressed = { [self] in
        print("Cell")
    }
}
```

**`add this in your cell file`**

```
  var buttonPressed : (() -> ()) = {}


   @IBAction func btnclick(_ sender: Any) {
        buttonPressed()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add target for that button.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Set tag of that button since you are using it.

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

Achieve this by subclassing UITableViewCell. button on that cell, connect it via outlet.

To get the tag in the connected function:

```
@objc func connected(sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
}
```

Answer (score -2):

2 am answer: You're over thinking this. Create a custom TableViewCell class; set the prototype cell class to your new custom class; and then create an IBAction.