# how to interact with custom UICollectionViewCell cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewController, which scrolls vertically(like a tableview). I created a custom UICollectionViewCell. Inside of a custom cell, there are checkmarks. I need some kind of event to click when the user clicks on a checkmark.

What I tried, was overriding:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("clicked")
    }
```

but that only executes when the use clicks on a cell. But, asI stated above, the cell contains checkmarks...I need to find out when each individual check mark is clicked.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you put more code of your cell class?

Comment: Of course it is possible: Hope this helps : [link:  closures and delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105189/how-to-add-a-button-with-click-event-on-uitableviewcell-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an IBAction to the `UICollectionViewCell` class and handle the tap from that IBAction, if you need it to change something on the Parent view controller you have a couple of options, you can use a delegate or pass the controller to the cell.

On the parent view controller :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.controller = self 
    return cell
}
```

On the UICollectionViewCell class:

```
var controller: ParentViewController? 

@IBAction func checkmarkPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    print("checkmarkPressed")

   controller.someFunction()

}
```

Comment: wow this is good thanks. However, in my custom UICollectionViewCell cell, I have created 4 labels programatically. I will need to change the text, when someone clicks on the cell inside of the CollectionView. Is there away I can name each label, so that I know which each label is inside of the cellForItemAtIndexPath ?

Comment: You can create IBOutlets for each of your labels in your CollectionViewCell and then you can access each one of them from the cellForItemAt, like cell.labelOne, cell.labelTwo and so on.