# How can I fix action button after update Xcode 12?

Tags: swift, xcode

My action buttons stopped working after Xcode update (Xcode 12). When I clicked the buttons, I saw that the functions did not working **(like there is no button in there)**. I could not understand why. These buttons placed in `TableView Cell`. How can I fix these functions?

Here my action button function:

```
   @objc func addAction(sender: UIButton) {
       let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! customCell
       cell.count += 1
       cell.countBasketLabel.text = "x\(cell.count)"
       
       let detailGelen = detailsModel[indexPath.row]
       selectedItemName.append(detailGelen.itemDetailName!)
       selectedItemPrice.append(detailGelen.itemDetailPrice!)

       UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedItemName, forKey: "urunadi")
       UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedItemPrice, forKey: "urunfiyat")
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

Here my button code:

```
       let addButton: UIButton = {
           let button = UIButton(type: .system)
           button.setImage(UIImage(named: "add"), for: .normal)
           button.tintColor = .black
           button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
           button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testdetail.addAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
           return button
       }()
```

**Edit:**

I downloaded the old version of Xcode(11.5 (11E608c)). When I run with Xcode 11.5 IOS14 works buttons but when I run with Xcode 12 IOS 14 not works buttons.I haven't found the solution yet. I am open to advices.

**Edit 2:**

I made sure there was a bug in **Xcode 12**. Because `ScrollToIndex` was also not working and when I simulated it with **Xcode 11.5** it worked too.(In IOS 14 and below)

Comment: try use `lazy var addButton: UIButton` instead `let addButton: UIButton`. I've checked and it should work as expected.

Comment: I did as you said but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Very strange, I've tested your code with Xcode version 12.0 (12A7209) with `lazy var` for `UIButton` and `addAction` was called correctly. Maybe there are any issues with adding of button. I just added `addButton` to navigation bar from code in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Really strange, This buttons inside custom tableview cell. But I didn't figure out why is this not working. Other buttons working in my app so maybe tableview cell cause this?

Comment: well, I prefer use closures (callbacks) and you can check [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105465/5928311). I've tested your code without implementation into custom cell.

Comment: I assume callbacks turn nil because when I debug in action function code never triggered. Maybe problem about Xcode update or something wrong when installation continue. What is your opinion can Xcode have trouble with installation?

Comment: I'm not sure that issue related to Xcode. I'd research deeper implementation of code. Also try clean DerivedData folder and rebuild your project

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, my buttons click doesn't work on the simulator or real device after updating to Xcode 12..clicks work on the same project works on Xcode 11 (verified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the button directly to cell contentView and it's worked for me.

```swift
cell.contentView.addSubview(button)
```